# How to copy a child record data from source to destination in xslt mapping

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, biztalk

I have a source xml as below

```
<customerSource>
  <Name>abc</Name>
  <Account>123</Account>
  <AccountInfoSource>
    <AccountLocaiton>Florida-MI</AccountLocaiton>
    <AccountZip>12341</AccountZip>
    <AccountBank>BOA</AccountBank>
    <AccountBalance>0.0001</AccountBalance>
    <AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
  </AccountInfoSource>
  <Employed>Yes</Employed>
</customerSource>
```

I can have any elemets in AccountInfoSource. So, I have to copy AccountInfoSource Record data into AccountInfoDestination, Can you please help?

I'm trying as below

```
<ns0:customerDestination>
  <ns0:Account>
    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:customerDestination/ns0:Account" />
  </ns0:Account>
  <ns0:AccountInfoDestination>
    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:customerDestination/ns0:AccountInfoSource/text()" />
  </ns0:AccountInfoDestination>
  <ns0:Employed>
    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:customerDestination/ns0:Employed" />
  </ns0:Employed>
</ns0:customerDestination>
```

The output should looks like this.

```
<ns0:customerDestination>
  <ns0:Account>123</ns0:Account>
  <ns0:AccountInfoDestination>
    <ns0:AccountLocaiton>Florida-MI</ns0:AccountLocaiton>
    <ns0:AccountZip>12341</ns0:AccountZip>
    <ns0:AccountBank>BOA</ns0:AccountBank>
    <ns0:AccountBalance>0.0001</ns0:AccountBalance>
    <ns0:AccountStatus>Active</ns0:AccountStatus>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
  </ns0:AccountInfoDestination>
  <ns0:Employed>Yes</ns0:Employed>
</ns0:customerDestination>
```

Comment: You've tagged your question with _both_ xslt-1.0 _and_ xslt-2.0 - which one do you actually need?

Comment: Try using xsl:copy-of ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged your question with both `xslt-1.0` and `xslt-2.0`, which makes no sense because those tags are meant to be mutually exclusive. The solution below works for both versions of XSLT, because an XSLT 2.0 processor can handle XSLT 1.0 documents as well.

The most important template:

```
<xsl:template match="AccountInfoSource/* | Account | Employed">
```

matches all child element nodes of `AccountInfoSource`, `Account` and `Employed` elements. Then, it constructs new elements that are prefixed with `ns0:`:

```
<xsl:element name="{concat('ns0:',local-name())}">
```

The text content of those elements is then copied unchanged to the output tree.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.namespace.com">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/customerSource">
        <ns0:customerDestination>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ns0:customerDestination>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Name"/>

    <xsl:template match="AccountInfoSource">
        <ns0:AccountInfoDestination>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ns0:AccountInfoDestination>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AccountInfoSource/* | Account | Employed">
        <xsl:element name="{concat('ns0:',local-name())}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

Note: The expected output you show is not well-formed because there is the `ns0:` prefix, but the namespace is not defined.

```
<ns0:customerDestination xmlns:ns0="http://www.namespace.com">
   <ns0:Account>123</ns0:Account>
   <ns0:AccountInfoDestination>
      <ns0:AccountLocaiton>Florida-MI</ns0:AccountLocaiton>
      <ns0:AccountZip>12341</ns0:AccountZip>
      <ns0:AccountBank>BOA</ns0:AccountBank>
      <ns0:AccountBalance>0.0001</ns0:AccountBalance>
      <ns0:AccountStatus>Active</ns0:AccountStatus>
   </ns0:AccountInfoDestination>
   <ns0:Employed>Yes</ns0:Employed>
</ns0:customerDestination>
```